# mantis new user registration without email

Tags: mysql, mantis

Mantis needs the new user to click on a link received in a mail. As per company policy, the sendmail (or any other) application can not be active on server. How do I allow users to register without a valid e-mail?

Is there anyway I can run an update query and change the password directly in the database and hand it over to the user?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. Create the user normally via `http://path/to/mantis/manage_user_create_page.php` (using an existing admin account)
2. Open a command prompt and log into MySQL (`mysql -u root -p`)
3. `use bugtracker;`   (where *bugtracker* is the name of the mantis bd; default = bugtracker)
4. `update mantis_user_table set password=md5('password') where username='username';`

The whole cmd exchange looks like this:

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin>mysql -u root -p
>   Enter password: `*********`
>   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MySQL connection id is 7 to server version: 4.1.21-community-nt
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.
>
> mysql> use bugtracker;
>   Database changed
>
> mysql> update mantis_user_table set password=md5('password') where username='username';
>   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
>   Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

Answer (score 9):

Yes, I had the same problem. If you have one working account (after install there is the admin user) you can copy the password of this account (in the database) and paste it into the new user(s).

You can find the users in: mantis_user_table.

if you use this hash: 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99 the new password is: password

Answer (score 7):

https://mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html-desktop/#admin.user.create

add $g_enable_email_notification = OFF to the config_inc.php file.  This will set the user's password to blank instead of sending them an email. You can either ask them to change it on first time login or login in for them (without password) and create a password for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use XAMPP on Windows, you simply access phpmyadmin page (localhost/phpmyadmin/)
You select bugtracker database, and then in last table from DB, mantis_user_table, you insert your user-with a simple mysql statement, there are a lot of columns, not all are mandatory.
The most interesting column is access level. For admin account access level value is 90, but I am not pretty sure how this number works. Until now I discovered a table: mantis_project_user_list_table and access level is set default to 10 (I suppose that this is a "normal" user level).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `config_inc.php`:

```
$g_enable_email_notification = OFF;
$g_send_reset_password = OFF;
$g_validate_email = OFF;
$g_check_mx_record = OFF;
```

Credit to: https://mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=799

Answer (score 0):

I followed the configuration suggested by @Cody Adams & @Pierre ...

After making these changes in **/var/www/html/ithd/config/config_inc.php**, i go to reset password in Manage Users ... The passwords resets as blank.

Next i login to user with blank password and change it myself or tell it to the concerned users to do it themselves. This is better than updating the password directly in DB.

Thanks @Cody Adams & @Pierre ...